# prevent socket.io-client to disconnect when there is onbeforeunload

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket

There is a use case, for example when the user wants to leave the webpage we ask him confirmation through wndows.onbeforeunload and then want to end the session with socket.io, but as soon as the user presses the close button, the disconnect event is already emitted to socket-server, before
the confirmation from wndows.onbeforeunload.

expectation:- socket disconnect should only be emitted after the user actually leaves the webpage.
after confirmation from wndows.onbeforeunload.

This was working fine in socket.io-client 2.1.3.

Comment: Might be related https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3639 Also see docs https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#closeOnBeforeunload and this https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client/commit/dcb85e902d129b2d1a94943b4f6d471532f70dc9

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.